# Through REST API how to get information about bamboo build plan that were aborted or never build?

Tags: java, rest, bamboo

I am creating a project in java to delete bamboo plans. There are 180 projects and 470 plans in bamboo. I am trying to fetch those plan which were not run for more than 1 year and delete it. Using Bamboo Rest Api `https://{base-url}/rest/api/latest/result/PROJECTKEY?expand=results.result` I am able to get plans but its not returning all plans. Plans that were never build or plans that were aborted during build are missing in that.

Is there a way to get info about all the plan, if plan was never build I need its creation date if it was ran and aborted in middle than I need its last build date.

Bamboo version I am using is 6.8

Comment: Sounds like a question that is more specifically about the bamboo rest api than java or rest

Comment: they don't have any documentation on their filters?

Comment: This is the documentation https://docs.atlassian.com/atlassian-bamboo/REST/6.8.1/

Comment: It says it gets all plans and doesn't mention anything about exclusion.